# MySQL query with JOIN or different solution

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this query:

```
select start, end, surname, name, id from employee, absences where surname LIKE '$surname%' and name LIKE '$name%' and start LIKE '$start%' and name LIKE '$end%' order by start ASC
```

I am aware that this is not a good way to search. I tried to use a JOIN for this, but I failed. I have two tables: absences and employee, simply connected by a FK, which gives me too many results(multiplied).

How do I use a join for this? Or is there another solution?

Tables_

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `absences` (
`absences_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee_FK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start` date NOT NULL,
  `end` date NOT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `approved_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type_FK` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1371 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
`employee_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `on_off_FK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of tables?

Comment: It's in the start post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join with the condition

```
    select a.start, a.end, e.surname, e.name, e.id 
from employee e
JOIN absences a ON e.employee_id=a.employeefk
where e.surname LIKE '$surname%' and e.name LIKE '$name%' and a.start LIKE'$start%' and a.end LIKE '$end%'
order by a.start ASC
```

try this I have updated it according to your table

**Now try this**

Comment: Did you use id as primary key? id is just a unique number each employee has, for the primary key I use employee_ID. I think the JOIN needs to go on employee_FK, right?

Comment: yes I was confuse about your primary key.. now i have updated my answer

Comment: @habibulhaq : well you just beat me to the same answer, so no problems with editing them same

Comment: I will try it and I think I start to understand how to use it.

Comment: hahahahahhaah @PaulF I was in so hurry that Mistakenly i have edited your post :p

Comment: I would have edited yours to add the underscore in employee_fk, but that is only a single char change which isn't allowed

Comment: I used this: select a.start, a.end, e.surname, e.name, e.id 
from employee e
JOIN absences a ON e.employee_ID=a.employee_FK
where e.surname LIKE '$surname%' and e.name LIKE '$name%' and a.start LIKE'$start%' and a.end LIKE '$end%'
order by a.start ASC but I got an error, mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, which means basically an error.

Comment: can you show us the php code ?? plus try this query in mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.start, a.end, e.surname, e.name, e.id 
from employee e
JOIN absences a ON e.id=a.Id
where e.surname LIKE '$surname%' and e.name LIKE '$name%' and a.start LIKE'$start%' and a.end LIKE '$end%'
order by a.start ASC
```

try this I have updated it according to your table

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
I have added some place holder where u need to put column required to fetch and also on join condition which to use

```
select {column name comma separated} from employee e
INNER JOIN absences ON e.id=absences.id {here u need to specify which column to use for joining two column}
where surname LIKE '$surname%' and name LIKE '$name%' and start LIKE '$start%' and name LIKE '$end%'
order by start ASC
```